# trying to make a webview take the entire screen

Tags: java, android, webview

I am loading a web url without a web browser in my android application. So, I am trying to make a webview to fit the entire screen of the window but it not working. I have set the webview as fill_parent in the width and height but still not working. as shown:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prog1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="2dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then in my activity class I have this code as shown:

```
final ProgressBar Pbar;
        //final TextView txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tV1);
        Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prog1);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://unitytimes.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress < 100 && Pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                    Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    //txtview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                Pbar.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    //txtview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Please how can I make the webview to take the entire screen of the window

Comment: what is parent layout code of webview?

Comment: Have shown the entire xml file. It has no parent layout if I am not mistaken

Comment: "but it not working" what do you mean?

Comment: Pardon my wordings! I mean not taking the entire screen of the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all these

```
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

`padding` is a gap between the boundary and the content of that view so here the content is `webview` and boundary is your layout  plus for best practice you should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`